# Парсер на Beautifulsoup + Selenium не парсит элементы со всей прокручивающейся страницы (бесконечный скролл)

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, beautiful-soup

Идея – парсер, который собирает артикулы только без картинок, т.е. с содержанием src в виде файла с расширением svg.

Но страница прокручивается полностью, а парсятся максимум первые 30 артикулов.

```
import bs4
import requests
import collections
import logging
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger('wb')

ParseResult = collections.namedtuple(
    'ParseResult',
    (
        'brand_name',
        'url',
    ),
)
HEADERS = (
    'Brand',
    'Link',
)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    'C://Users/roman/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Lib/site-packages/selenium/common/chromedriver_win32 (1)/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://upakovka-spb.ru/category/2-odnorazovaya-posuda/11-kontyeynyery/')
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

source_data = driver.page_source
soup = bs(source_data)


class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.session.headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit / 537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 84.0.4147.89 Safari / 537.36'
        }
        self.result = []

    def load_page(self, page: int = None):
        url = 'https://upakovka-spb.ru/category/2-odnorazovaya-posuda/11-kontyeynyery/'
        res = self.session.get(url=url)
        res.raise_for_status()
        return res.text

    def parse_page(self, text: str):
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
        container = soup.select('div.s-product-block')
        for block in container:
            self.parse_block(block=block)

    def parse_block(self, block):
        # logger.info(block)
        # logger.info(' ' * 100)
        url_image = block.select_one('img[src$="svg"]')
        if not url_image:
            logger.error('image')
            return
        image = url_image.get('src')
        if not image:
            logger.error('yesimage')
        brand_name = block.select_one('h5.s-product-header')
        if not brand_name:
            logger.error(f'no brand_name on {url}')
            return
        brand_name = brand_name.text
        brand_name = brand_name.replace('/', '').strip()
        logger.info('%s, %s', url_image, brand_name)

    def save_result(self):
        path = 'C:/Users/roman/PycharmProjects/new/product_scraper/result.csv'
        with open(path, 'w') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            writer.writerow(HEADERS)
            for item in self.result:
                writer.writerows(item)

    def run(self):
        text = self.load_page()
        self.parse_page(text=text)

        self.save_result()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = Client()
    parser.run()
```

Второй вариант

```
import bs4
import requests
import collections
import logging
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger('wb')

ParseResult = collections.namedtuple(
   'ParseResult',
   (
       'brand_name',
       'url_image',
   ),
)
HEADERS = (
   'Brand',
   'Link',
)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
   'C://Users/roman/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Lib/site-packages/selenium/common/chromedriver_win32 (1)/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://upakovka-spb.ru/category/2-odnorazovaya-posuda/11-kontyeynyery/')
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

# Get scroll height


import time
counter = 0
for _ in range(8):
   driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, arguments[0]);", counter)
   counter += 1000
   time.sleep(2)



source_data = driver.page_source
soup = bs(source_data)


class Client:
   def __init__(self):
       self.session = requests.Session()
       self.session.headers = {
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit / 537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 84.0.4147.89 Safari / 537.36'
       }
       self.result = []

   def load_page(self, page: int = None):
       url = 'https://upakovka-spb.ru/category/2-odnorazovaya-posuda/11-kontyeynyery/'
       res = self.session.get(url=url)
       res.raise_for_status()
       return res.text

   def parse_page(self, text: str):
       soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
       container = soup.select('div.s-product-block')
       for block in container:
           self.parse_block(block=block)

   def parse_block(self, block):
       # logger.info(block)
       # logger.info(' ' * 100)
       url_image = block.select_one('img[src$="svg"]')
       if not url_image:
           logger.error('image')
           return
       image = url_image.get('src')
       if not image:
           logger.error('yesimage')
       brand_name = block.select_one('h5.s-product-header')
       if not brand_name:
           logger.error(f'no brand_name on {url}')
           return
       brand_name = brand_name.text
       brand_name = brand_name.replace('/', '').strip()
       logger.info('%s, %s', url_image, brand_name)

   def save_result(self):
       path = 'C:/Users/roman/PycharmProjects/new/product_scraper/result.csv'
       with open(path, 'w') as f:
           writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
           writer.writerow(HEADERS)
           for item in self.result:
               writer.writerows(item)

   def run(self):
       text = self.load_page()
       self.parse_page(text=text)

       self.save_result()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   parser = Client()
   parser.run()
```

Comment: вы можете пройтись по страницам, их всего 4 судя по `s-paging-wrapper is-lazy-loading -> s-paging-list`

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно прокручивать ее несколько раз, так как страница увеличивается в размерах

```
def scroll(driver):
    import time
    counter = 0
    for _ in range(4):
        driver.execute_script(
            f"window.scrollBy(0, {counter});")
        counter += 1000
        time.sleep(2)
```

Выполните функцию после чего парсите данные.

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger('wb')

ParseResult = collections.namedtuple(
    'ParseResult',
    (
        'brand_name',
        'url',
    ),
)
HEADERS = (
    'Brand',
    'Link',
)

driver = webdriver.Chrome('')
driver.get('https://upakovka-spb.ru/category/2-odnorazovaya-posuda/11-kontyeynyery/')
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

# Get scroll height


import time
counter = 0
for _ in range(8):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, arguments[0]);", counter)
    counter += 1000
    time.sleep(2)



source_data = driver.page_source
soup = bs(source_data)
```

Comment: Если вставить рекомендованную Вами функцию между
 last_height = new_height
и
source_data = driver.page_source
то все так, как и было, ничего не меняется... Что я делаю не так?

Comment: вот так работает

Comment: во втором варианте головного сообщения - добавила функцию, как Вы сказали - результат тот же, парсятся первые 30. Ума не приложу, где ошиблась.

Comment: это странно, я тестировал, у меня было все в порядке